# pairwise.wilcox.test() after friedman.test() in R

Tags: r, statistics

Can I use `pairwise.wilcox.test()` for post hoc test as my `friedman.test()` gat sifnificant?
I can't install `pgirmass` for the `friedmanmc()` function as its not compatible with my R version.
Does `pairwise.wilcox.test()` make sense for more than two samples?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't offered a specific example or an explanation of the the study design and hypotheses being tested, but the documentation does say that "corrections for multiple testing" are made, so you should be reasonably safe on statistical grounds. (There is some debate about the need for multiple comparisons tests.)

On the topic of the other package, you are misspelling its name and there *is* a current version available from CRAN for pkg:`pgirmess`. After reading the documentation of the two tests, I would probably trust the `pairwise.wilcox.test` more than the `friedmanmc` test because it is in a core R package, while the `friedmanmc` test appears to have undesireable behavior that gets suppressed in an awkward fashion, leading me to think it uses something of a statistical hack. I'm not encouraging you to do so but if your unstated R version is somewhat older, there may be suitable package versions, since I see versions going back to 2005 in the [Archives](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pgirmess/).

Comment: Acutually I got different results with the pairwise.wilcox.test and the friedmanmc - thank you for the hint!